# Intermittent HttpClient issue - SslStream disposed

Tags: azure, azure-functions, dotnet-httpclient

I am having an intermittent issue with `HttpClient`. It randomly disposes `SslStream` ahead of time. It sometimes happens once an hour, sometimes more often. I am running my code on Azure Functions and it seems to be working flawlessly locally, but once I deploy it on Azure, it starts failing.
I know about the pitfalls of `HttpClient` and thus I am using the `IHttpClientFactory` in my implementation, which is injected in my API.

I am using microservices and this issue only affects calling another Azure Function app.

My `HttpClient` timeout is set to 5 minutes and Azure Functions timeout is set to max. 10 minutes, but that doesn't help.

The error message and stack is below:

```
The operation was canceled.. Inner Exception: The read operation failed, see inner exception.. Cannot access a disposed object.

Object name: 'SslStream'.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamInternal.ReadAsyncInternal[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Huedash.Core.HttpClientService.GetAsync[T](String service, String endpoint, ValueTuple`2[] parameters) in C:\_Huedash\HuedashApiGit\HuedashApiCore\Huedash.Core\HttpClientService.cs:line 43
   at HuedashConnectorsApp.WarehouseScheduleFunction.WarehouseDownload(Vendor vendor, IConfiguration configuration, IHttpClientService client, ILogger log) in C:\_Huedash\HuedashBackendGit\HuedashBackendCore\Huedash.ConnectorsApp\WarehouseScheduleFunction.cs:line 140
```

Comment: so you're reusing the same httpclient ? because you have a max number of connection allowed per app instance

Comment: How long are these requests that are failing? Azure App Service (which includes Functions) has a limit of 230 seconds for requests. Anything longer will be terminated. Is it possible you're hitting that?

Comment: Really? Does it only handle 230 seconds? Do you know any way to overcome it? I thought the limit is dictated by Azure Functions, which default to 5 minutes (up to 10 minutes on Consumption plan).
Oh, and I am using Durable Functions, if that is of any help.

Comment: Where you able to find a workaround? I`m having the same problem.

Comment: Have same problem. I'm downloading file in Azure Function. When download takes more than 2 minutes  I receive this error. Having Azure functions v3 and .Net Core 3.1